# Gradle conflicting with Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Up from 6.6.1 to 7.2 version of gradle ruined all the build.[image]

My $JAVA_HOME, gradle version, java version:
[image]

My idea's settings:
[image]

Deleting .idea, restarting not helpful at all.
Also, running terminal from Idea shows error during gradle -version command:
[image]

Where should I start at, opinions?

Comment: Why do you think this is an IntelliJ issue? Looks to me like you upgraded Gradle and then a Gradle plugin called "org.unbroken-dome.test-sets" started to fail as it is not compatible with that version. You probably just need to update it to a newer version as well. In any case, please post your Gradle build file(s).

Comment: Well, it looks correct. Our inner dependencies do not support latest gradle versions.

Comment: According to their releases page, you need v4.0.0 to work with Gradle 7 https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin/releases